# Determining configuration files location used by vsfpd in Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, vsftpd

I made some changes to vsfpd.conf, but they are not taking effect. I suspect that it is using a config file from another location. Is there a way to determine whether or not it is using the configuration file that I edited?

I edited the vsftpd.conf from '/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf'.

Comment: Which vsftpd.conf did you modify? Where was the file located?

Comment: @terdon edited /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Fedora-provided VSFTPD package, then you edited the correct config file. Did you restart / reload the service after you made the changes? If you wish to confirm the config file it is using, simply run the daemon (vsftpd) by itself inside an strace. You'll need to stop the main service first, and this will produce a LOT of output, so you'll probably want to pipe the output to a file, kill the process almost immediately after starting, and go through the file to find the config entry.

Comment: @Jafar, also check that you do not have a local `~/.vsftpd.conf` or `~/.config/vsftpd.conf` or similar.

Comment: thanks . I confirmed with strace that is using the default config file at /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf. I think I need to ask another question about my configuration. thanks.